# Docker container ac-database does not start for AzerothCore

Tags: azerothcore

I've cloned the latest version of AzerothCore-WotLK at https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk

Building the docker containers works fine, but when running `docker-compose up -d` I get:

```
[+] Running 2/7
 - Network azerothcore_ac-network  Created                                                                                      33.1s
 - Network azerothcore_default     Created                                                                                      32.7s
 ✔ Container ac-client-data-init   Started                                                                                       8.0s
 ✘ Container ac-database           Error                                                                                        32.4s
 - Container ac-db-import          Created                                                                                      29.9s
 - Container ac-authserver         Created                                                                                      28.6s
 - Container ac-worldserver        Created
```

`docker logs ac-database` shows:

```
2024-02-23 23:58:32+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.3.0-1.el8 started.
2024-02-23 23:58:40+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2024-02-23 23:58:40+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.3.0-1.el8 started.
'/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
2024-02-23T23:58:40.304564Z 0 [System] [MY-015015] [Server] MySQL Server - start.
2024-02-23T23:58:40.626109Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.3.0) starting as process 1
2024-02-23T23:58:40.836960Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-02-23T23:58:41.259500Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012960] [InnoDB] Cannot create redo log files because data files are corrupt or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files.
2024-02-23T23:58:41.260424Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2024-02-23T23:58:41.647600Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2024-02-23T23:58:41.648064Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2024-02-23T23:58:41.648122Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2024-02-23T23:58:41.651066Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.3.0)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2024-02-23T23:58:41.651123Z 0 [System] [MY-015016] [Server] MySQL Server - end.
```

Some things I've tried:

- Pruning volumes or even running `docker system prune -a` makes no difference.
- Restarting docker makes no difference.
- I've tried to find more logs or error information, but to no avail so far. I'm not very experienced with docker though.

Software used:

- Windows 10 (Version 10.0.19045 Build 19045)
- Docker version 25.0.3
- Docker compose version v2.24.5-desktop.1
- WSL version 2.0.14.0

Any ideas on what I can do to further debug this?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a disk space issue.

Despite Docker being configured to store disk images on D:, `docker-scout` ends up taking a lot of space in `C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Local\Temp\docker-scout`.

Cleaning up some space on C: resolved this for me.